# Connecting choices to buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I want to make an interactive story in windows form and connect choices to buttons. So that I will have something like...

```
        richTextBox1.Text = "Would you like to...
                            1. Kill a dragon?
                            2. Run away?
                            3. Talk to a dragon."

        if ( button choice )
        {}

        if else ( button choice )

        {}

        else ( button choice )
        {}
```

And then I have 3 buttons on my form named 1, 2, 3. How can I use these buttons to make choices in a program?

Comment: You just have to implement a method with the code above which takes an argument `int buttonChoice`. Then call that method from your button-click events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   button1.Click += button_Click;
   button2.Click += button_Click;
   button3.Click += button_Click;
}
```

And:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    if (btn.Name == "button1")
    {
       // do something here according to..
    }
    else if (btn.Name == "button2")
    {
      // do something here according to..
    }
        ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Give them all the same click handler and then check the `sender` to determine which button was clicked

Comment: I am trying to it this way  var btn = sender as Button;
            if (btn != null)
            {
                if (btn == btn1) but it doesn't work

Comment: @SergZ. all off the button will be instantiated so none will ber null.

Answer (score 0):

Should look something like:

```
    private void btns_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = sender as Button;
        if(btn == btn1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Choice 1");
        }
        else if (btn == btn2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Choice 2");
        }
        else if (btn == btn3)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Choice 3");
        }
    }
```